# Turn vim paste mode off when it is turned on

Tags: vim

Title pretty much says it. Only thing to add is I am setting 3 modes at once.
Putting the following:

`map <F11> :set paste! number! rnu! paste?<CR>`

in **.vimrc** only works in normal mode. Adding `imap <F11> <Esc><F11>i<CR>` doesn't help much because it only turns it on, but not off and moreover you lose the ability to return to replace mode automatically (if that was on). Using `pastetoggle=<F11>` doesn't suit it, because I need to set other stuff as well.
Additional question: does **map** act equivalently to **nmap** since it doesn't trigger under insert/replace mode?

Comment: You want to turn it on from the editor or the `.vimrc`? From the editor try `:set nopaste`

Comment: I want convenience. I need to map a key to toggle it on the fly, so **.vimrc**, not the editor.

Comment: You might be interested in https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired - especially the `yo` and `yO` shortcuts that turn paste mode on, enter insert mode, and turn paste mode off again when you exit insert mode.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @dlmeetei I am trying to map a key to toggle **paste** **number** and **rnu**.

Comment: in normal as well as insert mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the following **.vimrc** combination did it:

`set number rnu pastetoggle=<F11> 
 nmap <F11> :set paste! number! rnu! paste?<CR>
 imap <F11> <C-o>:set paste! number! rnu! paste?<CR>`

Strange as it is, it doesn't double-toggle in normal mode.

One small caveat is that when toggling paste with **F11** under insert mode you are cycling between 3 modes.